# Is there any difference installing command line tools with xcode-select --install or through developer.apple.com

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

Is there any difference installing command line tools with `xcode-select --install` in the terminal and installing it through the graphical program from developer.apple.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference, no.